# BizTalk 2020 - always received empty value from WCF-WebHTTP adapter

Tags: biztalk

I'm trying to publish Biztalk orchestration as REST API but I'm having a problem where the value sent in the URL is not captured but instead the pipeline always goes with empty message.

Below are the details:

1. created incoming schema & property schema, promote Distinguished Fields and Property Fields
2. created outgoing schema
3. created received pipeline with

   a. JSON Decoder

     i. Add Message Body For Empty Message = TRUE

    ii. Root Node = root node incoming schema

    iii. Root Node Namespace = incoming schema namespace

   b. XML Disassemble

    i. Allow Unrecognized Message = TRUE
4. created orchestration with

   a. incoming port

   b. receive  - incoming schema

   c. construct message - outgoing message

   d. transform - incoming to outgoing

   e. send - outgoing message

   f. outgoing port
5. use BizTalk WCF Publishing Wizard to create a service and save as Received location
6. configure received location

   a. method WCF-WebHTTP - `<BtsHttpUrlMapping><Operation Name="Operation_1" Method="GET" Url="/buat?token={token}&amp;jenis_carian={jenis_carian}" /></BtsHttpUrlMapping>`

   b. did a variable mapping mapped to property schema

   c. use received pipeline created above

When I try using postman, the file created from send port always with empty value.

Incoming schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://testTiga.Schema_msgMasuk" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="https://testTiga.PropertySchema_msgMasuk" targetNamespace="http://testTiga.Schema_msgMasuk" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <b:imports>
            <b:namespace prefix="ns0" uri="https://testTiga.PropertySchema_msgMasuk" location=".\PropertySchema_msgMasuk.xsd" />
          </b:imports>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:element name="Schema_msgMasuk">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:properties>
              <b:property name="ns0:icno" xpath="/*[local-name()='Schema_msgMasuk' and namespace-uri()='http://testTiga.Schema_msgMasuk']/*[local-name()='nokp' and namespace-uri()='']" />
              <b:property name="ns0:dhmno" xpath="/*[local-name()='Schema_msgMasuk' and namespace-uri()='http://testTiga.Schema_msgMasuk']/*[local-name()='nodhm' and namespace-uri()='']" />
              <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='Schema_msgMasuk' and namespace-uri()='http://testTiga.Schema_msgMasuk']/*[local-name()='nokp' and namespace-uri()='']" />
              <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='Schema_msgMasuk' and namespace-uri()='http://testTiga.Schema_msgMasuk']/*[local-name()='nodhm' and namespace-uri()='']" />
            </b:properties>
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="nokp" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="nodhm" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Property schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://testTiga.PropertySchema_msgMasuk" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="https://testTiga.PropertySchema_msgMasuk" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo schema_type="property" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="icno" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="6277d7c5-ef2d-4b3a-898e-3574bb7d4469" propSchFieldBase="MessageContextPropertyBase" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="dhmno" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="9c017341-774d-4864-95bb-5caf64ef7ef6" propSchFieldBase="MessageContextPropertyBase" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Receive Pipeline
[image: Receive Pipeline]

Message Properties - Context
[image: Message Properties - Context]

Comment: Can you enable message body tracing, and see if the payload is coming in as expected on the receive location?  Also use the Orchestration debugger and put a breakpoint in, to see the message at the various stages in the Orchestration

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf. From the message tracing, there are 4 messages, 2 in pipeline and 2 in orchestration. The first message received in pipeline, the body is empty but in the contexts, the 2 variable with its value is there. The second message send from pipeline is empty. It seems that the pipeline detects the message is empty so it create an empty message based on the defined schema.

Comment: They are elements in the schema. i have 2 parameters that sent thru URL and both is in the schema & property schema.

Comment: i've included the schema & property schema. Thanks.

Comment: so sorry about that. i've added them as text.

Comment: Do you also have a XML disassembler in your pipeline? As this is what does the promotion of properties, and might also be needed to demote the properties to the message.  Can you see the promoted properties in the context properties of the message? As you can also  access promoted properties in an Orchestration

Comment: Yes, i have the XML disassembler and also i can see the promoted properties in the message context properties. I've included the screen shot of the receive pipeline & message properties for reference.

Comment: You can see them as Context Properties, however they are not Promoted if you look at the Type column they have "Not Promoted", hence they won't be getting demoted into the message payload.  Are you sure the namespace you are assigning in the JSON decoder in the pipeline matches that of the schema?

Comment: In the JSON decoder, i've set the namespace=http://testTiga.Schema_msgMasuk and the root node = Schema_msgMasuk. Is there anywhere else that i need to configure in order to promote the column?